# Issue with an exception from a class, how to get it to return the main-script?

Tags: list, class, exception, python-3.x, return

I'm having an issue with an exception in my class. I want it to return to my main-script if that's even possible, or any solution which will avoid any crashing of my program. I'll show you the code.

Here's the main script:

```
from requestnew import requestNew


def chooseCountry():
    countryc = input("Enter which country your city is in(in english): ")
    rq.countrychoice.append(countryc)

def chooseCity():
    cityc = cityc = input("Enter the name of the city: ")
    rq.citychoice.append(cityc)

def makeForecast():
    try:
        for day in rq.data['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday']:
            print ("Country: ", rq.countrychoice[-1], "City: ", rq.citychoice[-1])
            print (day['date']['weekday'] + ":")
            print ("Conditions: ", day['conditions'])
            print ("High: ", day['high']['celsius'] + "C", '\n' "Low: ", day['low']['celsius'] + "C", '\n')
    except Exception as e:
        print ("\nHave you typed in the correct country and city?\nBecause we got a" ,'"',e,'"', "error\nplease try again!")
        return menu


if __name__ == '__main__':
    """Introducion"""
    print ("\nThis program lets you see a weather forecast for your choosen city.")
    rq = requestNew()

    while True:
        try:
            print("\nWhen you have typed in country and city, press 3 in the menu to see the weather forecast for your choice.\n")
            menu = int(input("\nPress 1 for country\nPress 2 for city\nPress 3 to see forecast\nPress 4 to exit\n"))
            if menu == 1:
                chooseCountry()
            elif menu == 2:
                chooseCity()
            elif menu == 3:
                rq.forecastRequest()
                makeForecast()
            elif menu == 4:
                print ("\nThank you for using my application, farewell!")
                break
            elif menu >= 5:
                print ("\nYou pressed the wrong number, please try again!")
        except ValueError as e:
            print ("\nOps! We got a ValueError, info:", e, "\nplease try again!")
            continue
```

And here is my class code:

```
import requests
import json

class requestNew:

    def __init__(self):
        self.countrychoice = []
        self.citychoice = []

    def countryChoice(self):
        self.countrychoice = []

    def cityChoice(self):
        self.citychoice = []

    def forecastRequest(self):
        try:
            r = requests.get("http://api.wunderground.com/api/0def10027afaebb7/forecast/q/" + self.countrychoice[-1] + "/" + self.citychoice[-1] + ".json")
            self.data = r.json()
        except #?
```

As you can see above I use an exception in the `def forecastRequest(self):`. The problem is I don't know which exception and how to return it correctly to avoid any program crashes.

If you look at my main-script you can see that I have `while True:` to loop everything from the menu.

Everything in the program works correctly except if I press 3; `elif menu == 3:` without choosen both country from `def chooseCountry():` or city from `def chooseCity():`.
This is because I'm using a list in my class and then print it in the `def forecastRequest(self):` like this; `countrychoice[-1]` to get the last appended list-item from input. And when I press 3 in the menu without choosing country or city, the list will be empty.

My question is, is there any way to let the `except #?` in `def forecastRequest(self):` to return the user to the menu in my main-script? Or is there any other way to avoid the program of crashing if the list is empty when I try to make the request?

Sorry for my english, and sorry if my explaining is messy, I've tried my best for it to be relatively easy to understand as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want control to return to the main loop, catch the exception in the main loop:

```
elif menu == 3:
    try:
        rq.forecastRequest()
    except IndexError:
        # self.countrychoice[-1] will raise an IndexError if self.countrychoice is empty
        # handle error
    else:
        makeForecast()
```

Comment: Bah I was so focused it would have to be in the class, this works perfect, thank you very much! @unutbu